# Outlook VBA 2010: Accessing Non-default Calendar folder under "My Calendars"

Tags: vba, outlook

Outlook VBA 2010: I have Multiple Calendar Items under Navigation Group "My Calendar" other than the default "Calendar" item. How do I gain access to the rest of the calendar items that i have created?

Answer (score 2):

An `Outlook.NavigationGroup` contains a number of `Outlook.Folder` objects.
The following demo shows how to access the navigation group for calendars and the calendars within the group.

```
Sub CalendarDemo()
    Dim objPane As Outlook.NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As Outlook.CalendarModule
    Dim objGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder

    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    Set objGroup = objModule.NavigationGroups.item(1)

    For Each objNavFolder In objGroup.NavigationFolders
        Debug.Print objNavFolder.DisplayName & " " & objNavFolder.Folder.FolderPath
    Next
End Sub
```

See a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574897/outlook-2010-select-calendar).

Answer (score 0):

Where are these folders created? If they are children of the default Calendar folder, they can be accessed by folder name by first retrieving the primary Calendar folder using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)`, the opening the subfolder using `MAPIFolder.Folders.Item("My Folder Name")`